# xml: using conditioned attributes

Tags: xsd, attributes, conditional-statements, element

I'm looking for a way to realize a scheme, where an element does have an attribute "topic" only when its enumeration has a specific value like in the upcoming example:

```
    <article>
        <type>Blogpost</type>
    </article>
    <article>
        <type topic='news'>Article</type>
    </article>
    <article>
        <type>Comment</type>
    </article>
```

The challenge is to make it that the attribute will only be used when the value "Article" or "Documentary" is chosen. Furthermore I want only enumerations from predefined list to be valid. In case the right enumeration is chosen I want the attribute to be required in all other cases I don't want to have the attribute at all.
So far I tried the following schemes in order to do so but it doesn't work at all:

```
    <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:alternative test="@name='type'" type="type1"/>
        <xs:alternative test="@name='type'" type="type2"/>
        <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
    </xs:element>

(...)

    <xs:simpleType name="type1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Blogpost"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Comment"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Sentence"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="type2">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="type1">
                <xs:attribute name="topic" type="topics" use='required'>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Article"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Documentary"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType-->
```

I always get an error that any chosen element is '*not a valid value of "error"*'. The other example I tried worked to make use the attribute however it allowed any text and didn't care about the enumeration restrictions making it basicly useless:

```
    <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:alternative test="@ItemType='type'" type="type1"/>
        <xs:alternative test="@ItemType='type'" type="type2"/>
    </xs:element>
(...)
```

How do I do it that the same element does only have the attribute when it is actually the right enumeration and still the restrictions to enumerations are valid? Is my approach to work with xs:alternative the right one in order to have a same element one time with and one time without an attribute?
I was not able to figure out right test conditions in order to work with xs:assert.

Comment: You need to specify which version of XML Schema you are using. I suspect that XSD1.1 can do what you need.

Comment: Yes, I'm using xsd version 1.1 (<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">)

My suspicion is that I have either a syntax error or am not using the xs:alternative correctly. But my search for the solution is not making any progress.

Comment: Your examples do not match the problem statement. Please can you take 5 minutes to check everything again - then I might be able to help.

Comment: Well the first example is what I am aiming for (broken down to the point where I have the issue) when writing a new xml-file with this schema:
Several elements of the type "type" which can only habe the enumeration-values predefined in the xsd (Blogpost, Comment, Sentence, Article, Documentary). Furthermore the type-element is supposed to have an required attribute "topic" only when the value "Documentary" and "Article" is chosen.

Second and third example are my tries so far which were not successfull. Since they are not working, maybe I got it totally wrong? I'm kind of confused by now...

Comment: Still looks completely wrong to me. Surely <xs:element name='type' should be <xs:element name='article'. If not, please explain why not.

Comment: Ah, that is because of the task we were given to solve. I would agree, that normaly the enumeration could be presented as an attribute itself and probably it would make more sense as well. But we were specifically told that as a practice it is supposed to be an element.

Comment: If the tag name is 'article' then the element declaration should specify name="article". I cannot help any further until you correct that fault in your XSD.

Comment: I'm confused - so there is no other way but to declare the element name as an attribute as well?
I mean - this is what we are told to avoid. In the complete xsd the element "article" also has further elements implemented, like "text", "author", "date" etc. but I skipped them for my example because they are not relevant for this specific problem.

Comment: Sorry - I'm the one getting confused. Please ignore those comments. I was expecting to see an element declaration for the article tag. I should have noticed that the child tag is called 'type'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you again for your approach @kimbert.

With your help I was able to figure out the assertion that is fullfilling the demand. I just had to adjust your idea slightly:

```
    <xs:element name="type" type="type2" minOccurs="0"/>

    <xs:complexType name="type2">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="type1">
                <xs:attribute name="topic" type="topics"/>
                <xs:assert test="@topic and ($value eq 'Article' or $value eq 'Documentary') or not ($value eq 'Article' or $value eq 'Documentary')"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="type1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Article"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Documentary"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Blogpost"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Comment"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Sentence"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Like this the compiler now always demands the attribute "topic" in case the value "Article" or "Documentary" is asked for. In all other cases the attribute is ignored as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I now have a useful answer - sorry for the non-useful comments!

This question is almost identical yours: [XSD 1.1 alternative test the contents of text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709465/xsd-1-1-alternative-test-the-contents-of-text)
. On that basis, I suggest that you try something like this (not tested, because I don't have a XSD1.1 processor)

````xsd
    <xs:element name="type" type="type2" minOccurs="0"/>

    <xs:complexType name="type2">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="type1">
                <xs:attribute name="topic" type="topics" use='required'/>
                <xs:assert test="not ( @topic or ( @topic and ($value eq 'Article' or $value eq 'Documentary'))"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="type1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Article"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Documentary"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Blogpost"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Comment"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Sentence"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>```
````

Comment: Thank you already for this approach. However the compiler still demands the attribute "topic" for all sorts of "type1" and not only limited to when it has the value "Article" or "Documentary". But when it has another value and is getting the topic-attribute the assert fails. By the way: Your answer is not compiling. One bracet is missing and needs to be closed (should be: ```<xs:assert test="not ( @topic ) or ( @topic and ($value eq 'Article' or $value eq 'Documentary'))"/>``` )